# Problema con los Roles en NestJS

Tags: nodejs, nestjs

Estoy tratando de controlar las peticiones de mi backend validando Roles, ej:

```
    @Get('cliente')
    @Roles(roles.SUPER, roles.ADMIN, roles.CLIENTE)
    @UseGuards(RoleGuard)
    async getUsersCliente():Promise<User[]>{

        return  await this._userService.getAllWithRole(roles.CLIENTE);
    }
```

Con el decorador @Roles le paso los roles permitidos antes de ejecutar el servicio, el decorador lo tengo definido así:

```
import {SetMetadata} from "@nestjs/common";
import { roles } from "../entity-roles.enum";


export const Roles = (...roles: roles[]) => SetMetadata('roles',roles)
```

Por último valido el Role que hace la petición con el que le paso con el decorador en RoleGuard:

```
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import {Reflector} from "@nestjs/core";
import { roles } from '../entity-roles.enum';

@Injectable()
export class RoleGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private readonly _reflector: Reflector) {}

  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean  {

    const roles: roles[] = this._reflector.getAllAndOverride<roles[]>(
        'roles',[
        context.getHandler(),
        context.getClass()]
    );

    if(!roles){
      return true;
    }

    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const {user} = request;

    const hasRole:boolean = roles.includes(user.role);
  

    return user && user.role && hasRole;
  }
}
```

El problema que tengo es que aunque haya pasado el rol CLIENTE como válido, en RoleGuard solo llega el rol SUPER o ADMIN y no tengo ni idea de por qué. En const user si que recojo el role del usuario que realiza la petición correctamente.

Si alguien me puede echar un cable se lo agradecería un monton.

Answer (score 0):

Que tal Zalux Bienvenido,
Por lo que veo en tu codigo falta instalar y configurar lo siguiente:
instala:

```
npm install --save @nestjs/passport passport passport-local
```

En las peticiones de cada controlador que desees aplicar los roles te esta faltando esta dependencia:

```
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

    @Get('cliente')
    @Roles(roles.SUPER, roles.ADMIN, roles.CLIENTE)
    @UseGuards(AuthGuard(), RoleGuard)
    async getUsersCliente():Promise<User[]>{

        return  await this._userService.getAllWithRole(roles.CLIENTE);
    }
```

Puedes leer mas acerca del tema en la documentacion oficial:

[NEST JS](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication)

Saludos

Comment: Gracias por responder !! Al final estaba todo bien montado pero el proyecto no estaba compilando bien por eso no se reflejaban los cambios que realizaba a los roles. Todo se arreglo al hacer un rebuild, no sé que demonios ocurrió, a partir de ahora estaré mas pendiente  (>.<)